# In a managed environment why do we need IDisposable

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, idisposable

One of the major advantages of managed code is built-in memory management.  You don't need to track pointers, buffer sizes, release memory you finish with, etc, the *managed* aspect does that for you.

So why do we have an `IDisposable` interface?  [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) the interface is to deal with non managed resources like window handles, files, etc.  But why require me to explicitly call the `Dispose` method (or use `Using`)?

1. Why can't the CLR track when the object goes out of scope and call `Dispose` automatically then?

```vb
Public Function DoSomething() As String
    Dim reader As New StreamReader("myfile.txt")
    Dim txtFromFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Return txtFromFile '<==== reader goes out of scope after this line, so call Dispose automatically
End Function
```

1. At the very least, why won't the garbage collector eventually get to it and call `Dispose`?

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

Several people (here and in other answers that suggest `Using`) have suggested that garbage collection is not good enough because the GC only *eventually* gets around to collecting the `IDisposable`.  I don't understand why that argument distinguished between an `IDisposable` and any other object in .NET.  And before you say `IDisposable` objects are more resource intensive, consider:

1. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) from above says `IDisposable` is for unmanaged objects regardless of their resource requirements
2. I've seen some very resource intensive .NET objects (how about [System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) or [System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx)).

Comment: The CLR doesn't currently track when objects go out of scope.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you could implement it at compile time (which is what `Using` does anyways) or let the GC take care of it like any non-`IDisposable`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to compile all the amazing helpful information from the other answers into one place, here's what I feel are the keys to understanding why .NET **needs** an `IDisposable`.

## Resource Availability

1. The Garbage Collection scheme (ie "managed code") is *designed for* and very good at managing memory.
2. There are other types of system resources like: file handles, db connections, sockets, windows, processes, etc.
3. One of the key features of GC is that it leaves abandoned memory around until *something else* needs memory instead of cleaning it up as soon as possible.  That's good for memory (who cares what it does when it's not in use) but not so good for other resources.  They depend on being listed as available when they are in fact available.
4. Without `IDisposable`, non-memory resources (files etc) would not become available until the GC happened to finalize the object that acquired them in the first place, ie when the system needed that objects memory space.  That could be a) a long time, or b) never.

## Finalization

1. The GC finalizes objects in a non-deterministic order.  Worse, it splits the managed and unmanaged portions of object finalization.
2. That means, the GC may finalize the managed portions of an object *before* the unmanaged portions.  If the unmanaged try to call back in to the managed...

## Code Structure

1. There's no good way for the *compiler* to know when an object is "abandoned".
2. A `Using` block provides specialized scoping to a variable to inform the compiler, "After the end of this block, I'm abandoning this object".
3. This moves the onus of managing references on the *programmer* instead of the CLR (where it normally is).  If you pass a resource out of a `Using` block, you're likely to get a `NullReferenceException`
4. For the reasons discussed above, this burden really needs to be on the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, the CLR doesn't track when objects go out of scope.

Let's take your example:

```
Public Function DoSomething() As String
    Dim reader As New StreamReader("myfile.txt")
    Dim txtFromFile As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    Return txtFromFile '<==== reader goes out of scope after this line, so call Dispose automatically
End Function
```

What would actually be required is for it to analyze the entire body of the method, to check whether you've passed a reference to this reader to another method, or stored a reference in, say, a field.

It would *then* need to determine whether that other method has stored the reference somewhere, or called other methods, etc.

It would *then* have to *deduce*, if the reference is stored anywhere else, whether the intention is that something else will later use that reference and expect to find a non-disposed instance there.

Compare that with *your* knowledge. You *know* (hopefully) whether you've stored a reference elsewhere, or passed the reference to something else that has "taken ownership" of this disposable. If you know that neither of these has occurred, you can convey this knowledge to the compiler - by adding a `Using` block.

---

> Or in any event, won't the garbage collector eventually get to it and call `Dispose`?

If a) the object directly "contains" an unmanaged resource, and b) whoever implemented this object follows best practices, then they should have implemented a finalizer on this object that will perform cleanup on the unmanaged resources (usually by calling a method shared between the finalizer and `Dispose`).

However, you have no idea *when* the next garbage collection will occur. In the meantime, you may be denying access to the same unmanaged resource to other programs - or even another part of your own program. You should treat unmanaged resources as scarce. If someone's implemented `Dispose`, they want you to call it (either explicitly or via `Using`) when you know you no longer require access to that resource.

Comment: That explains why "out of scope" is an impractical way to call `Dispose`, but what about just leaving it to the GC?  Couldn't the GC check for `IDisposable`s and call their `Dispose` method before destroying them?

Comment: As I said to @jalf, there are already explicit `Close` methods defined for objects your probably want to *release* quickly.  The MSDN says `IDisposable` is for unmanaged resources, *not* for time sensitive resources.

Comment: @just.another.programmer - as I said in my final paragraph, it's not just about freeing them quickly - it's about making them available to other pieces of code (your own, or others). And no, the GC shouldn't just call `Dispose` since by the time the GC's getting involved, the `Dispose` method may not be appropriate.

Comment: Why would `Dispose` ever become inappropriate?  If the resource is abandoned, no one is tampering with it anymore... how would it become non-`Dispose`able?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the definition of a unmanaged object in MSDN?

Comment: @just.another.programmer - Because by the time the GC is cleaning things up, it's doing it in a non-deterministic order. Any managed object that the disposable tries to access may have already been finalized itself. That's why in the Disposable pattern, there's a split between managed resource cleanup and unmanaged resource cleanup. During `Dispose`, it's safe to access other managed objects. In the finalizer (the method the GC will call when cleaning up), it's no longer safe.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR doesn't track when an object goes out of scope. The point in a garbage collector is that it will *eventually* collect dead objects. But the keyword is "eventually". You have no guarantee as to *when* it happens, so if you need it to happen at a specific point, you have to do something to make it happen. Which is what `Dispose()` and `using` are for.

In general, the CLR *cannot* track when an object goes out of scope, because while it might no longer exist in the scope where it was created, a reference might have been passed to another function in another scope, perhaps on another thread.

When you create an object, you just get a reference to it. A reference like any other. The object doesn't live in the current scope, it has no special attachment to the site where it was created.

This is unlike the situation in C++, where when an object is created, that is where it lives, and the destructor will be called when you leave *that* particular scope (and if references to the object exist elsewhere, tough luck)

So this is one situation where you actually have to be a bit more careful and write a bit more code in a garbage-collected environment. You can't just rely on a resource's lifetime being bounded by the scope it's declared in, so you have to explicitly say when it should be disposed of.

Comment: If *eventually* is soon enough for non `IDisposable` objects, why is it not soon enough for `IDisposable`s?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But "soon enough" depends on the resource in question. If the only resource consumed by your object is memory, then "eventually" is generally soon enough, and you don't need to implement `IDisposable` or call `Dispose()`. However, what if the resource is a file handle? When you open a file, you don't want it to be closed *eventually*, you want it closed as soon as you're done with it. The same is true for a network connection, or a database connection, or perhaps a GPU context. With some resources, you want to control *exactly* how long they live

Comment: AFAIK, most resources that you want to control *exactly* how long they live provide a `Close` method of some sort *in addition* to `Dispose` (ie `FileStream.Close`, `IDbConnection.Close`).  And MSDN in my question specifically indicates this has to do with the *unmanaged* aspect of the object, not the time it is supposed to live.

Comment: Yes, and in those cases, `Dispose` will typically call `Close` as well, so that they're more or less synonyms. :) But `Dispose` works well with the `using` statement because it's part of a single common interface. And yes, for unmanaged resources, you typically need to do *something* to close/free the resource. But you also typically want to control *when* that happens. :)

Comment: @just.another.programmer: They do provide various close methods, but without `IDisposable` there would be no general way of ensuring that the a close/disconnect/whatever method would get called before they were abandoned.  `IDisposable` provides a common method for calling whatever method needs to be called before an object is abandoned.  A very useful feature, which was missing from Java until recently.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ language was designed to keep track of exactly when things went in and out of scope.  It was quite good at this in situations where objects had a clearly-identifiable "owner".  Unfortunately, there are many situations where objects have no particular owner as such.  For example, if some object `Foo` generates a string containing the characters "Hello" and passes it to some other object `Bar` which stores a reference to it, neither `Foo` nor `Bar` would have any way of knowing if and when the other object no longer needs the string.  C++ can deal with this situation by having a counter associated with each string, having any method that creates a reference increment that counter, and having any method that abandons a reference decrement it and, if the counter hits zero, delete the object.  Unfortunately, requiring methods to increment and decrement counters any time they pass around references to an object can be expensive, especially on multi-processor machines (since it's necessary to ensure that if e.g. a count equals 3 and two processors simultaneously create a reference to the object, one will bump the count from 3 to 4 and the other from 4 to 5, as opposed to having both processors see that the count is 3 and then both set it to 4, which would be a disaster).

A garbage-collection system avoids this problem by simply having programs pass around references without worrying about keeping track of when the last reference to an object gets abandoned or overwritten.  Any time the system decides that it should try to reuse some memory, it can freeze everything for a moment, examine which objects still have live references to them, and free up any memory that was used by objects that are no longer needed.  All processes must by synchronized when the system decides to initiate a garbage-collection cycle (different systems differ in how long everything must be frozen), but the costs of that may be far less than the costs of requiring inter-processor synchronization any time one routine passes a reference to another.

Garbage-collection systems work well for managing memory.  Freeing up the memory used by an object won't help anything until such time as the memory would actually be used for something if it was freed.  The fact that applications which don't need to use much memory may go for an arbitrarily-long time without performing any garbage collection is a good thing, since there's no harm having an object remain in memory needlessly when there's nothing else that needs the memory anyhow.  Unfortunately, the fact that an application isn't using much memory does not imply that there aren't any abandoned objects which have exclusive use of resources other than memory (e.g. things like files that are opened for exclusive access) and are preventing other would-be users of those resources from accessing them.  Systematic notification of objects when they are no longer needed is thus necessary to ensure that objects which have acquired exclusive resources don't hold them excessively long.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you have a long-running function, or if you've initialized a field in a long-lived class with an external resource, it's probably inadvisable to wait until the variable/field goes out of scope.

In addition, if a static field has been initialized like this, it will never go out of scope.